# How to fix 'readable native map to string '

Tags: react-native

What I was trying to do is save the value of email and password. But, every time I run this project I am facing this error. I am getting error `READABLENATIVEMAP TO STRING`. The details of the error are available on the screenshot link is attached below.

[IMAGE OF ERROR AND LOGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uph56.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, StyleSheet, Button, Alert } from 'react-native';

    export default class Login extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                loggedIn: true,
                isLoading: true,
                email: " ",
                password: " ",
            }
        }
        submitForm = () => {
            if (this.state.email == "" || this.state.password == "") {
                Alert.alert("PLEASE FILL EMAIL AND PASSWORD")

                if (this.state.email != "" || this.state.password != "") {
                    this.loginData();
                }
            }
        }
        loginData() {
            return fetch('http://192.168.1.150:8080/crm/api/api.php', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email: this.state.email,
                    password: this.state.password,
                }),
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    // return responseJson.data;
                    if (responseJson === 'Data Matched') {
                        // this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { Email: UserEmail });
                        this.props.onHomeviewPress(this.state.data);
                    }
                    else {
                        Alert.alert(responseJson);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }

        // handlePress = () => {
        //     this.props.onHomeviewPress(this.state.data);
        // }


        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "blue", fontSize: 28, marginLeft: 10 }}> Login</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        textContentType="emailAddress"
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        placeholder="Email"
                        placeholderTextColor="blue"
                        textAlign="center"
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({ email })}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                    />

                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        textContentType="password"
                        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        placeholderTextColor="blue"
                        textAlign="center"
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                    />

                    <Button
                        onPress={this.loginData.bind(this)} title="Login"
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        paddingTop: 23,
        marginTop: 150,
    },
    input: {
        margin: 15,
        height: 40,
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 5,
    },
});
```

Please check the screenshot and my code to detect the error and help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can add screen shot or log of error ?

Comment: HELLO JAYDEEP GALANI I HAVE POSTED MY LOGS SCREEN HOT PLEASE HELP ME OUT!